# Remove transparent mesh face from boolean object?

Tags: modifiers

This one's a bit confusing, but as show in the image below I have an invisible cube and an apple. The apple has a boolean modifier on it so as I move the cube into it it removes more and more of the apple. However, the face of the cube which is hitting the apple still seems to be visible (that's the black glitchy part,) and I'm not sure how to fix that. If you know how, please help. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: To me, that looks like shadow banding caused by low shadow bias values.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Select the cube object, go under Object Properties, scroll down to Viewport Display and change Display As to Wire. :)

[image]

Comment: If it is just a viewport method you are going for... You can also use the CTRL+H hotkey to hide the selected object(s). ALT+H to unhide all hidden objects.

Comment: @RandomPanda Hi! I tried hiding the cube but then I couldn't move it, thanks though! :)